# Java System properties in AS400

Tags: java, ibm-midrange

On what basis, user.language and user.country gets loaded ? `QLOCALE` value for the system i am using is , `'/QSYS.LIB/EN_US.LOCALE'`. But a job which runs from the other country say Italy, user.country and user.language are `'IT'` and 'it' respectively. On what basis these values will be loaded?

Comment: Did you check the java env variables ?

Comment: RUNJVA sets these at start up from the environment.

Comment: The exact problem is, same job runs for all the countries, for some countries user.language and user.country are getting loaded correctly.For Example France it is loading correctly with values as 'FR' and 'fr'. Where as for Italy the values are 'en' and 'US'. I am not able to figure out, on what basis these values are getting loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Check SystemDefault.properties file in user home directory. Check following links for more details about properties file and java properties.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzaha/sysprop.htm

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzaha/sysprop2.htm

Comment: I have checked the SystemDefault.properties file, I couldn't find anything except 'java.version=1.7' in that file.

Comment: what are the values for language in user profile for user from France and for user from Italy? Also, check whether Italian is included in list of installed secondary languages. If Italian is not installed, system will use system default (EN) when Italian is specified in user profile.

Comment: how to check which secondary languages are installed in the system?

Comment: Use command GO LICPGM and select option 20 "Display installed secondary languages"

Comment: Italian language is installed in the system. But the English language is not installed.

Comment: You can set locale in multiple places. What are the values for language in user profile for user from France and for user from Italy?  What are the values for language, locale in  SystemDefault.properties file in home directory for user from France and in home directory for user from Italy?  Please note that you can also change locale inside java  program. It is possible that your java application is changing locale using some other criteria.

Comment: The languages of user profiles for both Italy and France are French. In SystemDefault.properties file, apart from java version, nothing is there. It is sure that Java program is not changing locale value. Is that the language we are using for Italy user profile(French) is creating the problem?